# Npm private repo url with credentials

Tags: npm, npm-install

I have a private npmjs repo that I would like to install into a project. What is the url I can use to that will include the credentials so everything works ok on my build server? Something like:

`npm install https://username:password@npmjs.com/@myorg/radlibrary`

Answer (score 1):

You need to run `npm login`, which persists the credentials on the current machine, for the current local user. This is an interactive prompt, so you'll need to use something like the `expect` command to automate it (or just do it once manually and it'll stick).

I posted a script that can be used to constantly re-login/update these credentials [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52288468/656193). In my case, I'm logging into a private (self-hosted) repo, which periodically expires the credentials, so a more thorough re-login test is needed.